# Does it help increasing the JVM heap size when the heap size free percentage is above 50%?

Tags: java, jvm, weblogic

I have a J2EE web application running on MS Windows Server 2008. The application server is Oracle WebLogic 11G. The server has 32GB ram but users still keep complaining the application is very slow.

So I check the JVM config and find that the allocated heap size is just 1 GB while the server actually has 32GB ram.

Then I check the JVM heap size free percentage and find that even when the server is most busy, there is still 50% heap free.

So I want to know if it helps if I increase the heap size to say 2GB or 4GB.

As I have read some articles that when allocating too much heap size to a JVM, it will take a long time to perform garbage collection.

Comment: possible of duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565388/increase-heap-size-in-java

Comment: I know how to configure the JVM to allocate more heap size. But I am interested to know if it is beneficial to the application to allocate more heap size if the current free percentage is already > 50%.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to make an application faster is to use various tools and other sources of information that are available to you to figure out why it is slow.  For example:

- Use web browser tools to see if there is problem with web performance, etc.
- Use a profiler to identify the execution hotspots in the code
- Use system level tools to figure out where bottlenecks are; e.g. front-end versus backend, network traffic, disk I/O ... swapping / thrashing effects.
- Check system logfiles and application logfiles for clues.
- Turn on JVM GC logging and see if there is a correlation between GC and "sluggish" requests.

Then you address the causes.

Randomly fiddling with the heap / GC parameters based only on gut feeling is unlikely to work.

FWIW: I expect that increasing the heap size is unlikely to improve things.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase your heap memory to about 75% of physical memory .But chances for that to solve the 'slow problem' are way too low.Problem its not there , you should analyse duration of most used functions and see where it last longer than user should expect.